# Create User in Django through form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I want to have a user sign up form in Django, I know that for the Backend I should have something like this:

```py
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')


>>> user.last_name = 'Lennon'
>>> user.save()
```

However, I don't know how to make the Frontend. I've already looked up in the Django documentation and found the **UserCreationForm class** and it says it's deprecated.
What should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#forms.py

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
fields, plus a repeated password."""
password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = MyUser
    fields = ('email', 'date_of_birth')

def clean_password2(self):
    # Check that the two password entries match
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    # Save the provided password in hashed format
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

You should read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/) section of the Django Docs on authentication.